# Highlight extra white spaces and fixed length column in VIM

Tags: vim, vimrc

I want to highlight extra white spaces and fixed length column (e.g., 80 character in a line) using VIM

I created two vimrc rule in my `.vimrc` file

```
highlight ExtraWhitespacea ctermbg=darkred guibg=#382424
match ExtraWhitespacea /\s\+$/
highlight OverLength ctermbg=green ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

Now, problem is - these rules run exactly as I want if applied separately, but will not work together.

Am I missing something here? How do I debug this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that each `:match` command overrides the pattern of the previous one; they are not cumulative! Because of that, there are `:2match` and `:3match` variants. Use one of them:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkred guibg=#382424
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red guibg=#525252
2match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

Additional variants can be created with the `matchadd()` Vimscript function.

#### Notes

- Since Vim 7.3, there's a built-in `'colorcolumn'` option that enables highlighting of column(s).
- Your setup in `~/.vimrc` only works for the very first window; i.e. a `:split` will create a window that doesn't have those highlightings. You can fix that via autocmds (or by using the `'colorcolumn'` option).
- There are more robust and elaborate solutions for highlighting trailing
  whitespace, for example my [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

Comment: Works like charm !!!

Answer (score 2):

May be your colorscheme had overrided your configuration. You can add those lines at the end of `.vimrc` to prevent from overriding or just add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
" Highlight trailing white spaces
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkred guibg=#382424
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()

" Highlight long lines
highlight OverLength ctermbg=green ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
autocmd InsertEnter * match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
autocmd InsertLeave * match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```